# How to organize a dictionary based off the columns from an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, list, parsing, dictionary

I am attempting to organize information in an Excel spreadsheet into a dictionary. Here is an example of how the spreadsheet is structured:

```
Col 1     Col 2
Hello     World
Hello     Earth
Hello     Planet
Hello     Mars
Hello     Moon
Hi        Pluto
Hi        Neptune
Hi        Jupiter
```

I currently have Python code that imports each column into a list, which results to it looking like this:

```
['Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'Hi', etc]
['World', 'Earth', 'Planet', 'Mars', 'Moon', etc]
```

My end goal is to have a Python dictionary, where each key (contents of Col1) holds a list of the multiple values that is mapped to (contents of Col2). For example:

```
{
    'Hello': ['World', 'Earth', 'Planet', 'Mars', 'Moon']
    'Hi': ['Pluto', 'Neptune', 'Jupiter']
}
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a dictionary of the contents of an Excel spreadsheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574918/how-to-create-a-dictionary-of-the-contents-of-an-excel-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have you two columns in lists as such:

```
>>> col1 = ['Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'Hi']
>>> col2 = ['World', 'Earth', 'Planet', 'Mars', 'Moon']
```

Then simply use the `setdefault` method of an ordinary `dict` (or you could use a `collections.defaultdict` too)

```
>>> map = {}
>>> for key, element in zip(col1, col2):
...     map.setdefault(key, []).append(element)
...
>>> map
{'Hello': ['World', 'Earth', 'Planet'], 'Hi': ['Mars', 'Moon']}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `col1` and `col2` are the list of column values...

```
result = {}
for key, value in zip(col1, col2):
    if key in result.keys():
        result[key].append(value)
    else:
        result[key] = [value]
```

`zip(col1, col2)` merges the two lists, so you get...

```
[('Hello','World'),('Hello','Earth'),....]
```

We then loop through this list, and add the key to the dictionary if it is not present, or simply append to the list if it is.

Comment: While the way you're doing it works, it requires `key` to be looked-up in the dictionary multiple times, which is sub-optimal.